# Friend function works in msvc but gcc and clang rejects the code

Tags: c++

I am working with friend functions but facing one problem that seems to compile with MSVC but not with gcc and clang. Below is a reduced example to show the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class Outer
{
     struct Inner;
     friend void foo(); 
};

template<typename T>
struct Outer<T>::Inner
{
  template<typename S> friend void bar(typename Outer<S>::Inner);    
};
template<typename S> void bar(typename Outer<int>::Inner) //but this private access works in msvc but not in gcc and clang?  
{ 
   //typename Outer<int>::Inner k;   //doesn't work as expected in all compilers(including msvc) 
   std::cout << "bar called";
}
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo called";
    Outer<int>::Inner i;
    bar<int>(i);    
}
int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
    foo();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Y4oPnv45)

The above program works with msvc but not with gcc and clang. Gcc says `error: struct Outer<int>::Inner is private within this context`. What is the correct behavior.

**Also is there a way to make the program work with all compilers?**

Comment: My brain is just going like "what?" in multiple ways. Like "what" are you trying to do?  Are you trying to break the compiler on purpoese? And "what?" why is it even compiling on MSVC. And then mostly my confusion it what Inner is doing in your code... it just doesn't make sense (even with 30 years of C++ experience)

Comment: Looks like a msvc bug again.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Sorry but I tried creating a reduced example and removed all unnecessary things from the original code. So this might not look useful in its reduced form.

Comment: The question seems perfectly fine. It has an MRE and explains the problem(that msvc is accessing private field).

Comment: I'm also confused. Your friend declaration uses `Outer<S>`, but the `bar` definition below uses `Outer<int>`, why? Can't you just do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jf5xcT5E7)?

Answer (score 0):

MSVC seems wrong here since `Outer<T>::Inner` is a private member of `Outer<T>`.

> is there a way to make the program work with all compilers?

Yes, you can add a *friend template declaration* inside `Outer` so that function template `bar` is also a friend of `Outer` as shown below.

##### Method 1

Here we add a friend template declaration inside `Outer` for `bar`.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class Outer
{
     struct Inner;
     friend void foo(); 
     //added this friend template declaration
     template<typename S> friend void bar(typename Outer<S>::Inner);  
};

template<typename T>
struct Outer<T>::Inner
{
  template<typename S> friend void bar(typename Outer<S>::Inner);     
};
//-------------------------------------------v-------------->changed this int to S
template<typename S> void bar(typename Outer<S>::Inner) //works now in all compilers  
{ 
     
   std::cout << "bar called";
}
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo called";
    Outer<int>::Inner i;
    bar<int>(i);    
}
int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
    foo();
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dPeTbnsqT)

---

Note that in this particular case you can omit the complete friend template declaration inside `Inner` since you're not actually accessing anything private to `Inner` from `foo`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qWEch9K9E)

Comment: Can also drop the `friend` from `Inner`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you mean only the keyword `friend` can be removed or the whole `friend declaration`? If the latter, then [yes](https://godbolt.org/z/qWEch9K9E) here it can be removed since `foo` is not accessing anything private to `Inner`. I have added a note at the end for the same so that if OP might be using `foo` to access anything private to `Inner` then they must retain that complete friend declaration.

Comment: Yes, I meant the whole `friend` declaration.